# How to set Error Messages for a column Element if multiple rows

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to set an error message for an input tag if the Validator funtion throws an error or fails to validate.

I am able to validate the input but when error is displayed it is displayed to the complete columns elements where as I want for that particular col element.

I was thinking of using index but issue is how will I disable the span tag initially?

```
<td style="background-color: white;padding:0px;"  class="active">

<input  class="datepicker_recurring_start" ng-model="item.stdate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"  type="text" style="width:73px;height:25px;padding-left:5px;" ng-change="checkStartDate(item.stdate,$index)"/>

<span style="color: red;display:inline;margin-left:10px;" ng-show="startDateCheck" id="adFeeStartDate"> Invalid Start Date </span>

</td>
```

I am iterating array via ng-repeat so if I have multiple rows, I want error to be shown for first row and currently I am getting error for all rows column element where as only first row column element has been validated.

Here is the Code :

```
<tr class="newRow" ng-repeat="item in adjustedwrapfee.rows" >
    <td style="background-color: white;padding:0px;" class="active">
        <input class="datepicker_recurring_start" ng-model="item.stdate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" style="width:73px;height:25px;padding-left:5px;" ng-change="checkStartDate(item.stdate,$index)"/>
        <span style="color: red;display:inline;margin-left:10px;" ng-show="startDateCheck" id="adFeeStartDate"> Invalid Start Date </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Here is the Code

<tr class="newRow" ng-repeat="item in adjustedwrapfee.rows" >
         
<td style="background-color: white;padding:0px;"  class="active">

<input  class="datepicker_recurring_start" ng-model="item.stdate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"  type="text" style="width:73px;height:25px;padding-left:5px;" ng-change="checkStartDate(item.stdate,$index)"/>

<span style="color: red;display:inline;margin-left:10px;" ng-show="startDateCheck" id="adFeeStartDate"> Invalid Start Date </span>

</td>

Comment: Add the code in question itself.

Comment: Can you please share the validator function or what this function returns?